# Play framework Jobs JPA and magic

Tags: playframework, jobs

Can anyone indicate where all the magic happens for Play Jobs to be enhanced with JPA and transaction support.

I intend to write my own plugin and would like to give some objects the same support.
However this I can't find anywhere obvious where this magic happens for the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

The helpers method for enhancement are in the [play.classloading.enhancers](https://github.com/playframework/play/tree/master/framework/src/play/classloading/enhancers) package.

Concerning the models, it's the [JPAEnhancer](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAEnhancer.java) file which adds many methods (count, findAll, findById ...)

Comment: You can also refer to https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-morphia/blob/master/src/play/modules/morphia/MorphiaEnhancer.java to see the similar magic implemented in PlayMorphia module

Comment: What I can't figure out is how play gives support for jpa transactions in a job.

Comment: One thread = one transaction. I can't explain in detail, but see https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPA.java and https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAContext.java

Comment: It's hard to see the correlation between threads/jobs and jpa enhancement. I take it not every threads gain JPA Support. It does not even seems JPA support for jobs is done through traditional Play Enhancement. The only enhancement I can see for JPA are for model classes.